# CSS N:th child with gaps

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've been trying to make a colored table with even rows with class `item` a different color than the odd ones. 
Please, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="item">
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>info</td>
</tr>
  <tr class="item">
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>info</td>
</tr>
  <tr class="item">
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>info</td>
</tr>
  <tr class="item">
      <td>4</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>info</td>
</tr>
</table>
​
```

CSS:

```
table tr.item:nth-child(2n)
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

table tr.item:nth-child(2n+1)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

How to make it work in css?

**UPD1**

`<tr>` without class `item` must be on white background.
`<tr class="item">`'backgrounds must be red/yellow on even/odd positions.
    ​

Comment: Better get your requirements in the question sorted out first.

Comment: It's really strange, I thought this http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/x7XT5/7/ would work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table tr
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

table tr.item:nth-child(2n+1)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

update: Here you go:

```
table tr {
    background-color: white;
}

table tr.item:nth-child(n)
{
    background-color: red;
}

table tr.item:nth-child(4n+1)
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey remove the **class** and check in your `tr` and `css` file

and create easily

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/1/

and

**second method** is Live Demo http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/3/

**Updated** Live demo  http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/5/

Comment: Sorry, `info` must be on white backround, and each `<tr class="item">` must be `red/yellow`

Comment: hi @Lari13 I Check to this http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/4/ and define every tr class as like this demo

Comment: Hi @Lari13 if you don't write tr class than remove the css .item class and check to live demo http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/5/

Comment: Sorry, You misunderstood the question. I have to skip `<tr>` without class `item`. Others `<tr>` must be colorized with even/odd rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. No need to set the nth child.

http://jsfiddle.net/x7XT5/2/

You could also use odd & eeven keywords.

Comment: I need to skip elements without the class `item`.
And paint the elements with the class `item` with yellow/red backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think, you should use :nth-of-type instead of :nth-child, but
unfortunately, :nth-of-type doesn't work with classes, so I dont know any pure CSS solution.

You can always use:

```
table tr.item:nth-of-type(4n+3)
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

table tr.item:nth-of-type(4n+1)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Works for this example.

Comment: Which other element than `tr` do you expect? The only exception is presence or lack of `tbody` between `table` and `td, th`but that doesn't change anything here where we're taliking about siblings. Similar case: `li`. You know which elements are children of `ul` and `ol`... Only an `li` can be a sibling of another `li`

Comment: discussion is pointless, because it doesn't work anyway, but OP wants use :nth-xxx() pseudoselector with some `tr`s (not all table children, onty this with `class=item`) so :nth-of-type looks better than :nth-child.